# Windows 8.1 Remote Desktop Connection issue

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

I am using Windows 8.1 and am having trouble when using RDP to connect to servers from my domain from outside the network.
I can connect fine using the IP address but cannot connect when using the host name.

I've added the server's IP address and name to my local hosts file, I've enabled the NetBIOS over TCP/IP option in the network adapter properties and I've uninstalled and reinstalled the network adapter from the device manager. None of these solutions have worked.

When a ping -a is run against the IP address of the server, the correct name is returned and I can connect using the FQDN.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the entries in the hosts file?

Comment: <ipaddress> -tab- <hostname>
There is no # in front of the entries.

Comment: edit the <hostname> entry in the hosts file to <FQDN> and test again.
Example `10.10.10.110`   `host1.domain.com`

Comment: will this allow me to log onto the remote server with just the hostname then?

Comment: Might aswell try it out